# how to import csv file into neo4j NumberFormatException

Tags: csv, neo4j

I have followed steps of [maxdemarzi](https://github.com/jexp/batch-import#rels_indexcsv). And i took the csv datas of this [example](https://www.dropbox.com/sh/c1p4v2fys0ke3l7/3O5_3jnjdr).
However, it took this error when execute this command.

```
java -server -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -Xmx4G -jar batch-import-jar-with-dependencies.jar neo4j/data/graph.db BeerNodes.csv BeerRelationships.csv

Usage: Importer data/dir nodes.csv relationships.csv [node_index node-index-name
 fulltext|exact nodes_index.csv rel_index rel-index-name fulltext|exact rels_ind
ex.csv ....]
Using: Importer neo4j/data/graph.db BeerNodes.csv BeerRelationships.csv

Using Existing Configuration File

Importing 2351 Nodes took 0 seconds

Total import time: 2 seconds
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "1
,10000,isa"
        at java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.Long.parseLong(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.Long.parseLong(Unknown Source)
        at org.neo4j.batchimport.Importer.id(Importer.java:195)
        at org.neo4j.batchimport.Importer.id(Importer.java:163)
        at org.neo4j.batchimport.Importer.importRelationships(Importer.java:129)

        at org.neo4j.batchimport.Importer.doImport(Importer.java:214)
        at org.neo4j.batchimport.Importer.main(Importer.java:78)
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Convert your csv files to use `TAB` as field separator.

Answer (score 0):

Either do what Stefan said, or:

Configure your importer using comma as separator, with: `batch_import.csv.delim=,` 
in your batch.properties.

See: https://github.com/jexp/batch-import#csv-experimental