# Migrating mysql data to neo4j database

Tags: neo4j

I wanted to migrate data from Mysql to neo4j. I'm using Neo4j 2.1.2 64 bit installer on 64 bit windows machine.
I followed the blog in the link `http://maxdemarzi.com/2012/02/28/batch-importer-part-2/#more-660` where migrating data from postgreSQL is well well explained.

Even I took the same example and created the sames tables in mysql. After creating nodes and relationship tables in mysql, i exported them as a csv file . So that I can use them in the `batch import` command.
Here all my fields are varchar and row_number() fiels is also a varchar field.

I used the below command to export mysql's relationship table into myrels.csv file (same thing for nodes table):

```
SELECT  *
INTO OUTFILE 'D:/Tech_Explorations/BigData_Related/Neo4j/mqytoneo4j/myrels.csv'
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '"'
ESCAPED BY '"'
LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'
FROM
(
SELECT 'start' AS `start`, 'end' AS `end`,'type' AS `type`,'status' AS `status`
UNION ALL

SELECT `start`, `end`,`type`,`status`
FROM `vouch_rels`
) `sub_query`;
```

Used below query to load the mynodes.csv and myrels.csv o neo4j:

```
java -server -Xms1024M -jar D:/Neo4j/target/batch-import-jar-with-dependencies.jar    
neo4j/data/graph.db mynodes.csv myrels.csv
```

When i executed the above batch import query , it's giving me an error saying

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "1
,"1","python,confirmed"
```

Where **"1,"1","python,confirmed"** is row in the myrels.csv.

The above error might be because of some datatype or csv file issue but I'm not able to figure it out. Even I tried with changing different csv load options while loading from mysql to csv file. But still getting the same error.

Answer (score 3):

MySQL to Neo4j migration is not a straightforward export-load problem. The property graph needs to be clear for Neo4j and should be consistent with the MySQL schema. There is no way to automatically generate Neo4j property graph from MySQL schema to my knowledge. After the 2 schemas are well defined you can write your own migrations in any programming language.

**The python way to do the migration**

[py2neo](http://py2neo.org/2.0/) is a Python library that makes it easy to write migrations as it provides a ton of useful functions, option to run cypher queries, transaction support, etc.

I used py2neo in a project to migrate around 100MB data from MySQL to Neo4j. [Here](https://github.com/pramttl/mlistdata-mysql-neo4j) is the sample code for reference along with documentation. The data is not provided but the schema of both MySQL and Neo4j property graph is given.

P.S: I might have digressed from trying to address your problem. But I have written this answer as it might help readers who are looking to solve the MySQL to Neo4j migration problem using Python.

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest looking at the `LOAD CSV` Cypher option. There are detailed docs on the [Neo4j website](http://docs.neo4j.org/chunked/milestone/cypherdoc-importing-csv-files-with-cypher.html).

Basically, you can use a Cypher query like the following to import your data.

```
USING PERIODIC COMMIT
LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS FROM "file:/path/to/your.csv" AS csvLine
MATCH (person:Person { id: toInt(csvLine.personId)}),(movie:Movie { id: toInt(csvLine.movieId)})
CREATE (person)-[:PLAYED { role: csvLine.role }]->(movie)
```

If you wish to proceed with the Java batch import tool then I believe your file needs to be tab delimited not comma delimited.

Comment: I would like to use java batch import as i wanted to migrate data from mysql to neo4j. But why the csv files should be tab delimited? Is there any reason for that?

Comment: It has in bold type on the Github page https://github.com/jexp/batch-import#neo4j-csv-batch-importer that "You provide one tab separated csv file".

Comment: Also in the link `http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20597702/how-to-import-csv-file-into-neo4j-numberformatexception?rq=1` i found the same problem. There if i wanted to use comma seperated csv file , then i need to configure the `batch_import.csv.delim=,` my batch.properties. But where can i found the batch.properties file? Also i found one batch.properties file getting craeyed after running the batch-import commnad. In that file do i need to add `batch_import.csv.delim=,`?

Comment: Hi, After creating tab seperated nodes and relationship csv's i'm able to import nodes and relationships to neo4j. But when i start the neo4j server with database location changed(changed db location is pointing to newly created nodes and rels using batch-import), neo4j server is not getting started. Saying `Starting Neo4j Server failed: Error starting org.neo4j.kernel.EmbeddedGraphDatabase, D:\Neo4j\data\neo4j\data\graph.db` .

Comment: I'm getting the error as below: `o.neo4j.kernel.EmbeddedGraphDatabase - Startup failed: Component 'org.neo4j.kernel.impl.transaction.XaDataSourceManager@525c6957' was successfully initialized, but failed to start. Please see attached cause exception.: Component 'org.neo4j.kernel.impl.nioneo.xa.NeoStoreXaDataSource@49643715' was successfully initialized, but failed to start. Please see attached cause exception.: 'neostore.nodestore.db' has a store version number that we cannot upgrade from. Expected 'NodeStore v0.A.1' but file is version 'NodeStore v0.A.0'`I'm creating db using batch-import.